# OOP classes and variables python turtle graphics?

Tags: python, oop, turtle-graphics

We're trying to make the turtle color be coral and came across this.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

# case 1: assign variable
foo = Turtle()
foo.shape("turtle")
foo.color("coral")
Screen().exitonclick()

# case 2: use it w/o assign
Turtle().shape("turtle")
Turtle().color("coral")
Screen().exitonclick()

# case 3: methods directly in the module
from turtle import *

shape("turtle")
color("coral")
exitonclick()
```

[case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf0gM.png) = case 3

[case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E48ke.png)

In case 2 the `color()` method only fills part of the turtle.

In a more general scope,

```
class Object():

    def __init__(self):
        print("object created")

    def introduce(self):
        print("I am an object")

    def sleep(self):
        print("I am sleeping")


# case 1
foo = Object()
foo.introduce()

# case 2
Object().introduce()
```

Here, case 1 & 2 are the same.

Answer (score 1):

In case 1, you're modifying a unique turtle instance that you created:

```
# case 1: assign variable
foo = Turtle()
foo.shape("turtle")
foo.color("coral")
```

In case 2, you are creating a unique turtle instance, and changing its shape followed by the creation of a second unique turtle instance and changing it's color.  I.e. these are two *different* turtles and you've lost your handle to further control them:

```
# case 2: use it w/o assign
Turtle().shape("turtle")
Turtle().color("coral")
```

In case 3, you are changing the shape and color of the *default* turtle instance that is provided by the library for simple programs:

```
# case 3: methods directly in the module
from turtle import *

shape("turtle")
color("coral")
```